# Read text from file given specific indexes

Tags: c#, file, readlines

I have a file with some text content.
e.g. file name = RandomText.txt

```
string content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
```

I want to be able to extract content given specific indexes
e.g. get text from index 5 to index 10

which should return "ipsum"

Here are my attempt, which isnt doing exctly what i want..

```
int minRange = 1
int maxRange = 10;
int randomIndex = rnd.Next(minRange, maxRange);
string text = File.ReadLines(RandomText.txt).Skip(randomIndex).First();
```

(I think skip() in here used for lines rather than indexes, which isnt what i want really..)

any ideas?

Comment: please post more information about the content of the file. do you have linebreaks in it?

Comment: no, just continuous text, no linebreaks

Comment: If your start-index is 5 you start with the space, so the result will be: `" ipsu"`

Answer (score 1):

`File.ReadLines(RandomText.txt).Skip(` would skip a number of lines not a number of characters. Basically you could use the method [System.IO.File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return the entire file content as one string. Now you can take a substring from a certain start index with a certain length

```
int minRange = 1
int maxRange = 10;
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
int randomIndexStart = rnd.Next(minRange, maxRange);
int randomIndexLength = rnd.Next(minRange, maxRange);


string part = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\read.txt").Substring(randomIndexStart, randomIndexLength);
```